# ANTLR4 stop parsing section of file and put it to a accessible buffer (string)

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I would like to have grammar that would have it's structure strictly defined, but part of the structure should not be parsed by my grammar but put into some sort of a buffer (string) for later use.

My grammar looks like this:

```
grammar RSL;

rsl: sectionStructs? sectionProgram;

sectionProgram: 'section' 'program' '{' '}';

sectionStructs: 'section' 'structs' '{' structDef+ '}';
sectionName: ID;

structDef: 'struct' ID '{' varDef+ '}' ';';

varDef: ID ID ';';

ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
```

And my wish is to have this sort of parsing going on:

```
section structs {
    struct TestStruct {
        int var1;
        float var2;
        ...
    };

    struct Struct2 {
        int var1;
        ...
    };
}

section program {
    // Do not parse anything that would be in this section
    // just store it in a buffer for later use.
}
```

So all contents of `section program` should be stored in a string for a later use and no grammar rules should apply to program.

What is the best way of approaching this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a lexer rule that matches this `section program { ... }`:

```antlr
grammar RSL;

rsl
 : sectionStructs? SECTION_PROGRAM EOF
 ;

sectionStructs
 : 'section' 'structs' '{' structDef+ '}'
 ;

structDef
 : 'struct' ID '{' varDef+ '}' ';'
 ;

varDef
 : ID ID ';'
 ;

SECTION
 : 'section'
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*
 ;

SECTION_PROGRAM
 : 'section' S+ 'program' S* BLOCK
 ;

WS
 : S+ -> skip
 ;

COMMENT
 : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
 ;

LINE_COMMENT
 : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
 ;

fragment BLOCK
 : '{' ( ~[{}] | BLOCK )* '}'
 ;

fragment S
 : [ \t\r\n]
 ;
```

which would parse your input as follows:

[image]

Of course, if your language allows for things like string literals, you would also need to account for that in the `fragment BLOCK` rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bart. The language inside program block is C, so the string literals should be accounted for. Is it hard to add support for that because unfortunately I don't understand what's happening in the fragment BLOCK :(